# CLion greys out include

Tags: c++, clion

[Mycode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WuUW4.jpg)

Why is #include "string.h" greyed out and does it still include it even though its greyed out. This is the only CPP source file in my project and so I know I'm not including it in another file. My TA said that its probably using the CPP version of string but later in the course it'll be a problem because we need to use the "string.h" version of string so I'd like to make sure its still including "string.h" even though its grey.

Comment: No idea about CLion but `#include "string.h"` is wrong if you really want to use the `std::string` class (which you are doing). `#include <string>` would be correct. Perhaps the IDE noticed that you do not actually use anything from `"string.h"` and therefore _warns_ by turning it gray? Try changing it to `<string>`. I think that'll solve it.

Comment: <string.h> this is not c++ code. And as per usual Ted is correct about the Clion behaviour. It is greyed out because you don't actually use it. I'm pretty sure the iostream include will pull in <string>

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe Cheers! The only way to be sure to get the definition of `std::string` is to actually `#include <string>`. It's the only header that makes sure you have that definition. The `<string.h>` header is called `<cstring>` in C++ but that only brings in the C string functions into `std::` (and perhaps adds a few C++ specific details around them). It doesn't define `std::string`. Messy? Yes :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s greyed out if clion detects that you aren’t directly using something from the referenced header.
It isn’t always correct in it’s detection process.

In this case, it is. There is a difference between `string.h` and `<string>` as an include.